# checking validation of whitespace on string

Tags: swift, uikit

Inputting a value with 2 spaces and a string would enable the button "  test"

but my code already detects "  " whitespaces where the button is disabled but adding additional string on the whitespace enables the button

```
func validateAccountName(with accountName: String) -> Bool {
  let regex = "[^A-Za-zA-O-o-y]"
  let accountName = accountName.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")

  return accountName.isEmpty == false && accountName.range(of: regex, options: .regularExpression) == nil
}

func edited() {
  // check user input and allow update button to be enabled
  guard let inputText = textField.text, let viewModel = viewModel else {
    return 
  }

  if !inputText.isEmpty
     && inputText != viewModel.accountName
     && viewModel.validateAccountName(with: inputText) {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = true
  } else {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well what do you want to achieve?
If the goal is to reject everything that has any whitespaces you can use:

```swift
accountName.rangeOfCharacter(from: .whitespaces) == nil
```

But your regex already checks this as only Characters `A-Z`, `a-z`, `A-O`, `-` and `o-y` are allowed.
Maybe this is already what you want?

```swift
func validateAccountName(with accountName: String) -> Bool {
    let regex = "[^A-Za-z]"
    
    return accountName.range(of: regex, options: .regularExpression) == nil
}
```

Comment: What I want to achieve is inputting "  test" or "  " or "test  " it would disable the rightbarButton